# Filtering the atlas coverage layer by a different layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, expression, atlas

I need to create one map atlas for each municipal administration filtering the coverage layer (red rectangles = map sheets) by municipal administrations boundaries layer (green polygons). How is it possible to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: can't you just use the municipal boundaries as the atlas coverage?

Comment: What have you tried so far and how is it not working?

Comment: a) The layout created refers to the map sheet with a fixed scale of 1: 10000. b) I tried to create an intersection layer (map sheets - municipal boundaries) but I don't know how to create an expression that dynamically link each element of the intersection layer to the coverage layer and I have not found any example about. I also thought about the possibility of a spatial query but I have not found any example that concern atlas generation.

Answer (score 1):

First in atlas use the municipality green polygon by some name or code, then in the properties from red polygons use symbology by rules, and in the expression use `intersection(@geometry,@atlas_geometry)`, with this solutions I did something similar, my result was the municipality green, and the red polygons

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! For better quality and visibility screenshots, take a look at : https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ .